# Job control: How to kill a sudo job using the job id

Tags: bash

If I run jobs with `sudo` I can't `kill %1` them (Operation not permitted). My first thought was to use `sudo kill %1` instead, but that of course doesn't work either because it won't use the bash builtin `kill`. Is there a trick to make this work?

//
I know how to kill a process through it's PID. The question is specifically about how to use the job id to kill a sudo job.

Comment: `man kill`, `man ps`, `man pgrep`, `man pkill`, `help jobs`

Comment: Only the last one has anything to do with what I'm trying to solve and it doesn't have a solution. Any more specific hints?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here, but you can explicitly use the builtin instead of a command from your PATH through usage of `builtin`, e.g. `builtin kill`.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov You can't use builtins with sudo. `sudo builtin kill -l` gives `sudo: builtin: command not found`

Comment: *"sudo won't use the bash builtin kill"*. Aside from that, `sudo` won't see the same list of `jobs`. If you do `sudo jobs`, you won't see `%1` listed. So it will never work with `%1`. You have to use the actual PID (which is effectively what Parthian's answer is doing).

Answer (score 7):

```sh
sudo kill "$(jobs -p %1)"
```

**NOTE:** Technically the double quotes aren't necessary, here, because we know the output of `jobs` will be a PID, and so won't contain any characters in `$IFS`. However, quoting variables is always a good habit to be in. And to ensure you use quality coding practices consistently, they must be ingrained habits. `$(...)` is used over backticks because backticks are the old way of doing things and they're less visible. `$(...)` is the new hotness, relatively speaking. The new hotness is, in this case, a few decades old.

Comment: I was hoping that there is an elegant solution to that problem. Obviously that one is not elegant. What's wrong with trying to find an elegant solution for that? I thought there must be something built in for that, but it seems like I have to define an alias for that.

Comment: @S1lentSt0rm This is a one-liner. Doesn't get much better than that. My main beef with this question is that SF != code golf SE. If you know the canonical way to solve the problem is killing via PID, and that question is already answered, and the question of how to convert PID to JID is trivially answered by the documentation, this question adds data to the site without adding value. Granted, I'm part of the problem because I rose to the bait and answered the question. And I hate myself for it.

Comment: A simpler one liner is ``sudo kill `jobs -p %1` ``

Comment: @user I'd recommend developing the habit of never using backticks. They're the older method of command substitution, and were replaced by parens precisely because they handle nesting very poorly, and lead to readability issues. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/74972